# how to get individual valued from the json array..?

Tags: json

I got json array as output. could anyone explain me how to get indivual value from it for eg( C:/). The following is the json array

```
{"Name":["C:\/","D:\/","E:\/","F:\/","G:\/","My Documents","Microsoft Outlook","Microsoft Outlook Express","Opera","Mozilla","Internet Explorer Settings","FireFox","Desktop","Registry","SystemState"],"path":["C:\/","D:\/","E:\/","F:\/","G:\/","\/\/\/My Documents\/\/\/","\/\/\/Microsoft Outlook\/\/\/","\/\/\/Microsoft Outlook Express\/\/\/","\/\/\/Opera\/\/\/","\/\/\/Mozilla\/\/\/","\/\/\/Internet Explorer Settings\/\/\/","\/\/\/FireFox\/\/\/","\/\/\/Desktop\/\/\/","\/\/\/Registry\/\/\/","\/\/\/SystemState\/\/\/"],"hasChild":["1","1","1","1","1","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0"]}
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your language is JavaScript, you first need to parse the JSON (below I use jQuery's `$.parseJSON` method) and then access the appropriate property and array position. To retreive "C:\", you would do this:

```
var sJSON = '{"Name":["C:\/","D:\/","E:\/","F:\/","G:\/","My Documents"]}';
var oJSON = $.parseJSON(sJSON);
alert(oJSON.Name[0]); //displays C:\
```

If you're using JavaScript, you can use an `eval()` statement in place of a `$.parseJSON` because JSON is executable in JavaScript, but it is safer to use a `$.parseJSON`.

More on JavaScript `eval()`: [When is JavaScript's eval() not evil?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/197769/when-is-javascripts-eval-not-evil)

Answer (score 0):

Use a JSON parsing library for your language.

In JavaScript, [you can use JSON.parse](http://www.json.org/js.html). If your output is in the var `output`, you would do:

```
var obj = JSON.parse(output);
console.log(obj.path[0]);
```